# youtube from IOS mobile device not working as aspected

Tags: reactjs, youtube, react-player

When I'm using react-player with controls options and youtube video I cant press the volume and full-screen buttons because the title is hiding them and clicking on the video makes double click happen.

Using youtube iframe working as expected (the buttons move to the bottom bar) but I need to support multiple video platforms.

**Steps to Reproduce**

- go to https://cookpete.com/react-player/
- Turn on controls
- Click on one of the youtube tests

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the developer of the library, CookPete:

> This is not a problem with ReactPlayer. This library uses the YouTube
> Player API to play YouTube URLs and this looks like a recent change to
> that API that has broken things on mobile. Maybe try StackOverflow as
> per the Player API support page.

you can view the question and the answer [here](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player/issues/949)